# Error 403 - Forbidden error when I'm trying to access ?WSDLs from browser in WSO2

Tags: wsdl, wso2, single-sign-on

Dears, I'm trying to access this URL through my browser: https://localhost:9443/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService?wsdl
But I'm getting error 403

I followed everything based on [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/OAuth+Token+Validation+Using+SOAP+Service) doc,
please someone help me.

Comment: You may need to specify the IP address (instead of localhost).

Answer (score 1):

If you set `<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>` and restart the server this should work.

Answer (score 0):

First understand what the 403 error means.

The error (HTTP 403 Forbidden) means that the browser was able to connect to the website, but it does not have permission to view the webpage.

So, check the user under which the process is running. If that user is not having the right permissions, then this error will pop out.

Kill the process id, and start the server with the correct user who is having the right permissions.